# How to limit items per order line but not per order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site with just one customisable product. I'd like the customer to be able to add multiple instances of that product to their order, but individually. ie to remove the quantity per line item.

So the order summary would look like:
Product A with options 123 = £10
Product A with options 345 = £20

Rather than:
Product A x2

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.